# team viewer 10 and TV11 on same PC

Tags: windows-7, teamviewer

would it be possible to run teamviewer 10 and teamviewer 11 on the same PC without uninstalling one? TV10 currently installed.
I tried to rename TV10 folders in appdata and program folder but it wouldn't let me - said file open. Found the open part via task manager, services to be in \appdata\roaming\microsoft\I??? but I was unable to read rest of name or find anything.
So i was thinking...
 **What are other ways i could alternately switch and run the one i wanted to match another PC's version?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your question because you still can remotely control a Teamviewer 10 PC, using your Teamviewer 11 which is installed on your computer. So why do you need to match another PC's version?

However, you can install Teamviewer 11 to your computer, then use a Portable version of Teamviewer 10, download via this link:

https://www.teamviewer.com/vi/download/previous-versions/

Comment: thanks. What I was trying to do was host a meeting from my TV10 but the other party has TV11 so is not able to join my meeting. I have probably 5 friends all with TV10 so it is usually not an issue. Since the other party with TV11 is important i did not want to have to tell them to change their version.

I have not heard the term portable version - will this help me?

Comment: problem solved, will share for others.....I have found out how someone can join you on TeamViewer10 meeting you are hosting without them having to install it.

Comment: For example if they have TV11 or no TV installed at all then there is a problem.
There is a Quick Join method not requiring a full installation....
First make sure any other versions of Teamviewer they have are fully closed. 
Then get them to download and run this link http://download.teamviewer.com/download/version_10x/TeamViewerQJ.exe  

You just host your meeting, send them this link, and give your meeting code mxx xxx xxx
From your end and their’s everything looks normal, screen sharing, sound, allow remote access etc. 
I just tested it on my laptop to my PC.